# BUG Update Contacts in Search Results, Relationship to Organization, Employee of, deleted Employee of Relationship Type

Tags: error, relationships, upgrade, deleted

ERROR "appears you have deleted the employee relationship type" BUT that is not the case, and now the summary view can't display/modify employer since doing a relationship update via search results/action.  So is something amiss in the code for doing relationship updates from search results?  This never happened to us before.  Didn't find anything similar on search in stackexchange.

This comes after the site was upgraded to CiviCRM 5.50.1 on Wordpress 6.0 site, mysql 5.7.36-39, php 7.4 on CiviHosting:
A fairly simple search by contactType (individual subtype).  Selected all results.  Clicked on ACTION dropdown, Add relationship to organization.  Selected Employee of, entered organizationName of employer (existing contact), selected radio button of employer's contact record organization name.  Under relationships we can see the "employee of" and the "employer" but in summary view it did not show up, it is blank; every time we try to edit employer on the summary page it says connection with server failed and/or pops up with "it appears you deleted employee of relationship type".  It one time also displayed a message above employer selection like "another user edited this record."
We checked the relationship types table in Civi and the database, it's in there as its default.  When we click to edit the contact's employer in summary view we see the employer's name, but trying to save it, says it failed to connect with server, say it appears employee relationship type was deleted, click save, and it shows up empty again.

Any help appreciated.  We want the employer to show up in summary view and relationships tab like it should, like it did.

Comment: What version were you on before?

Comment: Please edit the question and add a screenshot from `Administer > Customize Data & Screens > Relationship Types`.

Answer (score 0):

possible issue is that 'employer of' and 'current employer' are not the same thing.

'employer of' is purely a relationship

'current employer' is an additional field on the relationship which is what then causes that Organisation to show on the Contact Summary screen

Comment: not working for us either; same error message